# How to calculate the average value of non-zero elements

Tags: javascript

We have an array of 12 elements, there are elements with numerical values and there are elements with zeros.
How to calculate the average value of non-zero elements.

Is the element from which you need to get the average value by skipping zeros

```
for(var i in result){
                    if( i === 'Office 1'){
                        result[i].forEach(x=>{
                            x.Monthly_Expense__r.forEach(y=>{
                                office1.push({
                                            key : nameMonths[new Date(y.MonthDate__c).getMonth()],
                                            intMon : new Date(y.MonthDate__c).getMonth(),
                                            value : y.Balance__c,
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    }
                }
```

That's what I'm trying.

```
for(var i = 0; i < office1.length; i ++){
                    console.log(office1[i]);
                        averageValueOffice1 = totalOffice1 / i;
                }
```

In total, I get the average number divided by 12, and the elements with values in this array are only 2

This my code now

```
for(let i = 0; i < office1.length; i ++){
                         averageValueOffice1 = office1[i].value;
                         console.log(averageValueOffice1);
                         let nonZeroNums = averageValueOffice1.filter(item => (isFinite(item) && item!==0));
                         let total = nonZeroNums.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
                         let avg = total/nonZeroNums.length;

                }
```

If you comment on the code like this, here's what I get in console.log[image]
[image]
If you remove the comments
[image]

But here's my method, which works!!!!

```
var countOfExistBalances3 = 0;
                var resultAverage3 = office3.reduce(function(sum, curr) {
                    if (!!curr.value) countOfExistBalances3++;
                    return sum + curr.value;
                }, 0);
                var resultAverageOffice3 = resultAverage3 / countOfExistBalances3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with explanation:

```
// declare your array
let myarr = [{"key":"January","intMon":0,"value":0},{"key":" February","intMon":1,"value":0},{"key":" March","intMon":2,"value":0},{"key":" April","intMon":3,"value":0},{"key":" May","intMon":4,"value":0},{"key":" June","intMon":5,"value":0},{"key":" July","intMon":6,"value":0},{"key":" August","intMon":7,"value":0},{"key":" September","intMon":8,"value":0},{"key":" October","intMon":9,"value":400},{"key":" November","intMon":10,"value":434},{"key":" December","intMon":11,"value":0}]

// collect numbers and non-zero numbers
let nonZeroNums = myarr.map(item => item.value).filter(item => (isFinite(item) && item!==0));
console.log(nonZeroNums); // [400, 434]

// Get total of numbers
let total = nonZeroNums.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);

// calculate average
let avg = total/nonZeroNums.length;

console.log('avg ', avg); // 417
```

Refs:
1. [isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite)
2. [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: It doesn't work with my array.

Comment: @GariVudi, can you copy paste the array in question. You can get the JSON by using [console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: This my json.stringify log([{"key":"January","intMon":0,"value":0},{"key":" February","intMon":1,"value":0},{"key":" March","intMon":2,"value":0},{"key":" April","intMon":3,"value":0},{"key":" May","intMon":4,"value":0},{"key":" June","intMon":5,"value":0},{"key":" July","intMon":6,"value":0},{"key":" August","intMon":7,"value":0},{"key":" September","intMon":8,"value":0},{"key":" October","intMon":9,"value":400},{"key":" November","intMon":10,"value":434},{"key":" December","intMon":11,"value":0}])

Comment: But I'm getting numbers in this method:                                                                    
        for (var i = 0; i < office1.length; i++) {                                                                                                    
              var item = office1[i].value;

Comment: @GariVudi modified answer. no need of any for loops.

Comment: Thank you, dear friend. It works.

Comment: But here's my method, which works too.                                                               
                    var countOfExistBalances = 0;
                    var resultAverage1 = office1.reduce(function(sum, curr) {
                        if (!!curr.value) countOfExistBalances++;
                        return sum + curr.value;
                    }, 0);
                    var resultAverageOffice1 = resultAverage1 / countOfExistBalances;